# Hyper-V guests stuck after live migrating on 2016

Tags: debugging, hyper-v, hypervisor

I've been dealing with some issues on our cluster with guests getting stuck when they are live migrated. I've noticed the issue after applying the latest cumulative update to Server 2016 core, but I am just guessing.

[image: stuck vms]

First, let me give an overview of the environment:

- Server 2016 Core
- 3PAR 8200 SAN
- Ten nodes in a failover cluster
- Stuck VM's occurred on HV04 and HV11. HV11 was reinstalled fresh as HV07 on 2/13/2018 and joined back to the cluster. It is happening on HV07 today (picture above).

I have contacted Microsoft but they are less than helpful. They claim it is a WMI issue and I need to rebuild the MOF files but even if that is the case, I need to know what is corrupted so I can try to track down what is possibly corrupting it. I have taken a user process dump of the vmms.exe service and a kernel dump using livekd but I'm still researching on how to look at what the issue is.

Another thing I noticed is the Hyper-V Management Service is unable to stop when this issue occurs and I have noticed that the WMI service has issues stopping too. I'm not saying it ISN'T a WMI service but if it is then I need to way to find out what is causing this (if its a patch from Microsoft causing it).

Has anyone else ran into this?

Comment: I also want to point out this happens when live migrating. It has happened to both Gen8 and Gen9 HPE blades. Also it always seems to get stuck at 84% when this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have a patch now:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4077525/windows-10-update-kb4077525

Addresses issue that causes Hyper-V VMs that are replicated using Hyper-V Replica or Azure Site Recovery to stop responding at 92% if a Windows Server 2016 Failover Cluster is set up with NIC Teaming enabled.  The issue also occurs while stopping the VM, during Live Migration, while stopping the VMMS service, or during Host node shutdown. The user must then use a hard restart on the host machine to recover.